# Photoshop CS6 - Image - Crop

Tags: photoshop-effects

In photoshop CS6 why the crop is not activated in Image menu. I want to cut a particular part from my complete image and retain other parts

Comment: Are you possibly in Quick Mask mode? Get back into normal mode (hit Q)

Comment: Welcome user47229! Thanks for posting your question. Unfortunately, GD.SE is not designed to handle issues regarding technical support. If you are seeking technical assistance with an application, please try the application manufacture's web site. We are confident you will find answers. If you want to know more about GD.SE, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 0):

You **must** have a selection active in the document for `Image > Crop` to be available.

CS6 *may* have further required that the selection be *rectangular*, but I can't remember for certain.

Comment: yes the selection was active bt it didn't work